# Как обработать задачу и порождённые ею подзадачи с помощью ExecutorService?

Tags: java, task, concurrency

Создаётся `ExecutorService` (допустим, на 10 потоков), который выполняет определённые задачи типа `Callable<TaskResult>`.

Объект класса `TaskResult` содержит результат выполнения задачи и список подзадач типа `Callable<TaskResult>`.

Вопрос такой: как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения главной задачи все её подзадачи были выполнены в том же объекте `ExecutorService`, который выполнял эту главную задачу?

Также, важно то, что как только все задачи и их подзадачи будут выполнены, `ExecutorService` нужно выключить, т. е., приложение не должно висеть в фоне в ожидании новых тасков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом идея простая: сначала запустить выполнение первых задач, потом через `Future.get()` дожидаться выполнения этих первых задач как `TaskResult` со списком вторых задач и опять отправлять их в пул.

```
public class Application {
    // класс, который выполняет какую-то работу и создает результат
    @Data
    private static class Task implements Callable<TaskResult> {
        private String index;

        public Task(String index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public TaskResult call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 200));
            return new TaskResult(index);
        }
    }

    // результат работы со списком последующих задач
    @Data
    private static class TaskResult {
        private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        public TaskResult(String index) {
            for(int i=0; i < ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5); i++) {
                tasks.add(new Task(index + "_" + i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        // создаем задачи
        for(int i=0; i < executor.getMaximumPoolSize(); i++) {
            tasks.add(new Task(i + ""));
        }

        // запускаем выполнение задач
        List<Future<TaskResult>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

        for(Future<TaskResult> future: futures) {
            // получаем выполнение задачи и запускаем выполнение подзадач
            for(Task task : future.get().getTasks()) {
                executor.submit(task);
            }
        }

        // ждем завершения всех задач и останавливаемся
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Также почитал вашу предыдущую задачу, где вложенность тасков без ограничений. В целом нужно обернуть запуск и ожидание выполнения в рекурсивный метод, например:

```
public static void execute(List<Task> tasks) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<Future<TaskResult>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

    for(Future<TaskResult> future: futures) {
        execute(future.get().getTasks());
    }
}
```